# How to move "Collapse Menu" to top of admin bar?

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu

As stated in the title, I try to perpetually move the "Collapse Menu" button which is normally the very last entry in the admin sidebar (backend) to the top.
I googled but can't find any working solution.

I found that it is printed through `wp-admin/menu-header.php`. 
So I thought I could override this file with my child theme. But then, when a theme update changes the `menu-header.php` file, I would need to realize and reproduce these changes in the child theme as well. Not very practical...

Anybody got an ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb is **do not** modify any core WordPress files. Those in the root, wp-includes, wp-admin. You could do this easily with JavaScript:

```
/**
 * Move the 'Collapse menu' item to the top of the admin menu
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse348570_move_collapse_menu() {

    ?>
        <script>
            if( jQuery( '#collapse-menu' ).length ) {
                jQuery( '#collapse-menu' ).prependTo( '#adminmenu' );
            }
        </script>
    <?php

}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse348570_move_collapse_menu' );
```

You can add the above as a plugin or place it into the child theme.

Comment: Absolutely awesome!! Works perfectly. Thanks a lot for that!